# R programming: how to cut dendrogram in 3 steps and show the plot in texts

Tags: r, machine-learning, dendrogram

Please refer to the attached code:

```
train <- read.csv("~/Desktop/R/2014data.csv")
d <- dist(train, method = "euclidean") # distance matrix
fit <- hclust(d, method="ward") 
plot(fit)
```

Here is the output figure:

[image]

How to cut this dendrogram in 4-5 layers and show the output (texts)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cuttree()` function to trim the tree to a specified depth i.e. 4 or 5. Then to show the tree in text simply `print(tree)`.

```
# As you had
train <- read.csv("~/Desktop/R/2014data.csv")
d <- dist(train, method = "euclidean") # distance matrix
fit <- hclust(d, method="ward") 
plot(fit)

# trim the tree, k for number of groups, h for height
fit.4 = cuttree(fit, h=4)
fit.5 = cuttree(fit, h=5)

# print the text or plot
print(fit.4)
print(fit.4)
plot(fit.4)
plot(fit.5)
```

Comment: Apologies, I specified the wrong argument to `cuttree`. I have edited the answer